# How to move element to another element in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I would like to move this element into another element. Sample

```
<div id="source">
...
</div>
```

into this

```
<div id="destination">
...
</div>
```

so I have something like this

```
<div id="destination">
  <div id="me-first"></div>
  <div id="source">...</div>
  <div id="last-here"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
        jQuery("#destination")
        .prependTo("#source");
    });
```

My problem is it will only transfer in the first place before me-first div. How do i put it in the middle of the me-first div and last-here div? Thanks

Here is the wrong placement after I ran my code.

```
<div id="destination">
  <div id="source">...</div>
  <div id="me-first"></div>
  <div id="last-here"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your elements have ID attributes, so use [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector)(prefix `#`) to select them, not [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector)(prefix `.`) which is used to select element by class name

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#source").prependTo("#destination");
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 10px;
}
#destination {
  border-color: red;
}
#me-first {
  border-color: green;
}
#last-here {
  border-color: blue;
}
#source {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="destination">
  <div id="me-first">
    <div id="source">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="last-here">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `prependTo()` won't put it between the elements he outlined in his DOM description.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.after()`:

```
jQuery('#me-first').after(jQuery('#source'));
```

This will place `#source` after `#me-first` in the DOM.